# Thread safe calls to windows form control from different constructor

Tags: c#

I read a MSDN article pertaining to thread safe calls to update a window form control the example is below

```
    private void setTextSafeBtn_Click(
        object sender, 
        EventArgs e)
    {
        this.demoThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));

        this.demoThread.Start();
    }


    private void ThreadProcSafe()
    {
        this.SetText("This text was set safely.");
    }



    private void SetText(string text)
    {

        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

This works great when i tried it if your thread is within the window form constructor. However say for example if the thread is in a different constructor to the windows form, How do you access it from the threaded constructor. I had attempted to do something like

```
          Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

However i tried it and it did not update the control, I read that if you create a new form that you are essentially trying to update the control of the new form rather than updating the intended one. Am i correct in anyway at all in my understanding and is there a solution to this?

I apologise if i am getting some terminology wrong, Trying to get a grasp of this all really

Comment: This is basic object-oriented programming, it doesn't have anything to do with threading.  You need a reference to the form object, that's the short and sweet of it.  Raise an event that the form can subscribe or pass a reference the the form object to the class.  If you are desperate then you could use a static variable or Application.OpenForms to find it back, avoid that.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what a "constructor" is. First of all, the form isn't fully constructed while in the "constructor", so you don't want to try to set an control values in there (it will either fail do nothing).  You should set initialize values in `InitializeComponent` or during/after processing the `Load` event.